# stop restarting asynctask on revisiting application

Tags: android

My application simply request the `json` data from `url` and displays it in `TableLayout`. I used `asynctask` to request the `json` data and then I use that `json` data to fill my `TableLayout`. It works correct but when i press `back` button and then i again come to application,It again  request the `json` data by running `AsyncTask`. I just want to stop calling `AsyncTask` again.so the `TableLayout` is filled up with same data twice. so how could i solve this problem?

Comment: change the calling of async task to on create method so it wont get called on resume

Comment: its already there and when come back to application it again request the data. i dont want the new request.i want to resume only. get it?

Comment: keep one variable which will get initiated when u start the async task & check that again while starting you async task

Answer (score 2):

Make global boolean rotation and use this :

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Here save the data you have
    outState.putInt("integer1", value);...

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

  @Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    value = savedInstanceState.getInt("integer1");...
           //fill your layout here
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    rotation = true;
}

   @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
 if(!rotation){
 //start AsyncTask here
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible cases: 
1.you are calling your async task in onResume better to place it onCreate if you want to load the data once.
2. Cancel the async task inside onStop or onPause or handle it properly in onResume.

Comment: then its still running in the background better to cancel it when you exit from activity and try to put it on resume so it call everytime when onresume will call but dont forget to close it while leaving the activity.
call asynctask.cancel either in onbackpress or better to call it onPause or OnStop.

Comment: how to close whole application ..do u know?

Comment: To close the application as suggested by commonsWare but its not a solution of your problem.

When I want to quit the app:

    I start my first activity (either splash screen, or whatever activity is currently at the bottom of the activity stack) with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP (which will quit all the other activities started after it, which means - all of them). Just make to have this activity in the activity stack (not finish it for some reason in advance).
    I call finish() on this activity